# Node.js + npm: как восстановить работу последнего и указать ему кастомный каталог для установки пакетов?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Ситуация такова. Есть установленный в `C:\Users\User\.phpstorm\node.js\4.4.0` `Node.js`, система - `Win 7 64 bit`. Установлен через установщик, вместе с `npm`. По умолчанию, после такой установки команда вроде `npm install less -g` будет устанавливать данный пакет в каталог `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm`, так как именно такое значение задано в `config prefix`, если проверить его через `npm config get prefix`.

Мне неудобно работать с двумя этими месторасположениями и хотелось бы свести их к одному, а именно к `C:\Users\User\.phpstorm\node.js\4.4.0\...`. Соответственно я попробовал выполнить команду `npm config set prefix 'C:\Users\User\.phpstorm\node.js\4.4.0'`. После этого `Node.js` успешно запускается из консоли, а вот npm запускается, но далее просто "висит" - никаких реакций в случае как с попытками изменить обратно переменную конфига, так и в любом другом, можно только лишь прервать его работу через `Ctrl + C`. Я попробовал удалить все из обоих упомянутых каталогов и запустить еще раз установщик интерпретатора, в режиме `Repair`. Интерпретатор восстанавливается успешно, а вот менеджер пакетов, то есть `npm`, работать все также отказывается. Попробовал и деинсталлировать и поставить заново - результат тот же. В связи с этим у меня два вопроса:

1. Как грамотно изменить упомянутую переменную?
2. Как грамотно очистить все, связанное с упомянутыми вещами, чтобы хотя бы заново все поставить как есть и вернуть на исходную точку?

Первый вопрос это программа максимум, в целом меня устроит ответ и только лишь на второй, если вдруг никто не сможет ответить сразу на оба вопроса.

Comment: Если запускать npm с ключом `--verbose`, то ничего подозрительного там не пишется? Возможно, будет понятно, на чем именно возникает затык.

Comment: @Yaant прошу прощения за предыдущий ответ, спросонья прочитал. В общем, реакция на `npm --verbose` аналогичная остальным - то есть никакой. Команда как бы начинает выполняться, но вывода никакого нет, можно только опять же прервать выполнение по `Ctrl + C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на второй вопрос найден: конфиг `npm`, по крайней мере та его часть, которая хранит переменную `prefix`, хранится по пути `$HOME/.npmrc`. Соответственно, удалив оттуда эту переменную с ее значением, работоспособность `npm` восстанавливается.

Ответ на первый вопрос: оказалось, что не нужно было брать значение устанавливаемой переменной в кавычки, в итоге в конфиге это выглядело вот так:

```
prefix="'C:\\Users\\Stas\\.phpstorm\\node.js\\4.4.0'"
```

Что и вводило в подвисшее состояние `npm`. Очевидно, что разработчикам данного инструмента было бы неплохо учесть такое и отбрасывать лишние кавычки, если они еще не сделали этого в более поздних версиях их инструмента или же самого `Node.js`.